# Appending to a list doesn't work while print works in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the authors and paper titles from DBLP API for a specific venue. Here is my approach:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "http://dblp.uni-trier.de/search/publ/api?q=bioinformatics%20type%3AJournal_Articles%3A%20venue%3ABioinformatics%3A&h=1000&format=json"
obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(obj)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append( data['result']['hits']['hit'], ignore_index=True)
mylist = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    mylist.append( {"title": row["info"]["title"], 
                "au": row["info"]["authors"]["author"] } )
```

The last line(authors part) gives error. However, it works perfectly fine when I try to print it as follows:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print {"title": row["info"]["title"], "au":row["info"]["authors"]["author"]}
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the error?  On of them has `"au"`, the other has `"authors"`.

Comment: Changed both to "au". The error is: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0d3bd0f12676> in <module>()
     11 for i, row in df.iterrows():
     12     mylist.append( {"title": row["info"]["title"], 
---> 13                     "au": row["info"]["authors"]["author"] } )

KeyError: 'authors'

Comment: If you check the json that returns the page you will see that it indicates author

Comment: your `print` example works perfectly fine... up until the line that is missing the authors key. This is the same line that your list append is failing on, but you probably just didn't notice that `mylist` is partially populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because one row doesn't have the "authors", you should find the error yourself.

just print(row["info"]), it will very easy to find the error.

```
{'url': 'http://dblp.org/rec/journals/bioinformatics/X03', 'pages': '1867-1868', 'year': '2003', 'venue': 'Bioinformatics', 'key': 'journals/bioinformatics/X03', 'title': 'The Fourth Georgia Tech-University of Georgia International Conference in Bioinformatics - in silico Biology, Biological Networks, from Genomics to Epidemiology (November 13-16, 2003, Atlanta, Georgia, USA).', 'type': 'Journal Articles', 'volume': '19', 'number': '15'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the dataframe you want, you can just pass `data` to the dataframe constructor, vs appending to it

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['result']['hits']['hit'])
d2 = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df['info'].tolist())],axis=1)
d2['au'] = d2.authors.apply(pd.Series)['author']
```

Comment: Im actually missing one conversion, your trying to extract the list of authors from the authors column, and one entry is not a dictionary, give me a second...